# Does Bell's theorem imply a causal connection between the measurement outcomes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, causality, bells-inequality

It is a standard result that quantum mechanics does not allow for superluminal communication, which would seem to directly imply that the answer to this question is *no*. After all, Bell's result tells us about *correlations*, and we know that *correlation does not necessarily imply causation*.

However, if we restrict our attention to solely the measurement outcomes, Bell's theorem also tells us that *we cannot think of the observations of Alice and Bob as correlated via a third variable*. In other words, it rules out the following causal structure:

[image]

More precisely, the result (stated in the CHSH formulation) is that, if there is an underlying probability distribution $p(a,b,x,y,\lambda)$ which is such that **(*)**
$$p(a,b|x,y,\lambda)=p(a|x,\lambda)p(b|y,\lambda),\tag1$$

*then* some functional relations between the values of $x, y$ and the conditional marginal distribution $p(a,b|x,y)$ are not possible.
In other words, (1) imposes restrictions on the following function:
$$f(a,b,x,y)\equiv \sum_\lambda p(a,b|x,y,\lambda)p(\lambda)=p(a,b|x,y).\tag2$$
These restrictions are made evident when taking expectation values over all possible outcomes, that is by studying the function $g$ defined as
$$g(x,y)\equiv\sum_{a,b}ab \,\,f(a,b,x,y).$$

In particular, it is not possible (and this is the content of CHSH result) to have something like
$$g(x,y)=\boldsymbol x\cdot\boldsymbol y.$$

Now let us consider the quantum case.
The full probability distribution has to be written in the more general form $p(a,b,x,y)$, and whenever a form of Bell's inequalities is violated by this distribution, then we know that we cannot factorize it with the help of an additional variable as in (2).

However, we can still assume that the measurement setups are chosen independently, so that we can still write
$$p(x,y)=p(x)p(y),$$
althought we *cannot* write $p(a,b,x)=p(a,x)p(b)$ or $p(a,b,y)=p(b,y)p(a)$.

My question is then precisely about these last statements: *does the fact that $p(a,b,x)$ cannot be factorized as $p(a,x)p(b)$ imply that there is a causal relation between the two measurement outcomes*?

---

### **(*)**

Eq. (1) can be equivalently stated as a statement about the structure of the full joint probability distribution describing $p(a,b,x,y,\lambda)$ the whole behavior:
$$p(a,b,x,y,\lambda)=\frac{p(x,y,\lambda)}{p(x,\lambda)p(y,\lambda)}p(a,x,\lambda)p(b,y,\lambda),$$
where every time a variable is not included as an argument we are talking about the marginal distribution with respect to that variable, so that for example:
$$p(a,x,\lambda)\equiv\sum_{b,y}p(a,b,x,y,\lambda).$$

Comment: I don't understand this question, and I think your previous posts show that you know better than the trivial readings on this post. Normally, we rule out causal connections between A and B by imposing a spacelike separation between them - how does that play a role in your question? And what is it you're actually asking?

Comment: To my mind, Bell-inequality violations are consistent with a model where there are local real variables that can have causal interactions "behind the scenes" between spacelike-separated events but which are somehow structured to make those causal interactions completely unavailable unless the events are timelike separated. But I find the fact that the causal interactions happen but are entirely inaccessible to us to be a worse fix than the initial problem.

Comment: "After all, Bell's result tells us about correlations" I think the jury is still out on this one. We have not achieved perfect testing and the improper detection or non-detection of photons arriving at exact times has led to discarding perfectly good sets. This skews the results but if and when perfect testing is achieved we will find the result to be 50/50

Comment: @BillAlsept what I mean here by "Bell's result" is solely the mathematical statement about correlations possible under given assumptions over the structure of the overall probability distribution. As such, it doesn't need to have any connection with physical reality. One can argue about "the jury still being out" on the experimental verification of the violation of Bell's inequalities, not about the mathematical result itself

Comment: @glS  The mathematical results are fine for the situation presented. It is almost a straw-man type situation. One way it is presented is with eight possible outcomes:

Comment: YYY, YXX, YYX, YXY, XYY, XXY, XYX, and XXX of which the results will never match the 50/50 predictions of quantum mechanics.

Comment: But this does not take into considerations the true outcome of the XXX or the YYY if tested to the full range of possibilities and not just limited to three outcomes. On a quantum level things are random and may vary from 0-100.

Comment: @user1892538 It is possible to construct models where you *can* have local variables that communicate FTL. They are extremely contrived models because you need to "shield" those causality violations from being available to humans, but they nevertheless exist. If you have further questions, ask them separately.

Comment: @user1892538 Local interactions with so-called hidden variables, ARE local and space-like separated. None of them are instant or spooky but take place at speeds no faster than light.

Comment: @user1892538 The variables do not and cannot communicate instantaneously. With perfect testing these correlations could be proven. If we were only talking polarization, two entangled photons should hit the target at exactly the same time with exactly the same polarization if they are truly entangled. Unfortunately the tests are not that accurate and more importantly Bell’ testing only breaks this down into three angles. You will never get the math to work with three. Of course it will always be unequal.

Comment: @user1892538 These are not separate because the OP precisely ends the question asking about the causal relation between the two ***measurement*** outcomes.

Comment: @user1892538 I agree, my point is it wouldn’t even be a question if there were perfect testing. Any phenomena can easily be derived with simple variables. They don’t need to be so mysteriously as hidden implies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It kind of does, but in a useless way.

The question is essentially equivalent to the following simplified version of it: suppose a probability distribution $p(a,b)$ cannot be factorized as $p(a)p(b)$. Does this imply that $A$ "causes" $B$?

The answer is: *not really*. The problem is that, from a purely probabilistic point of view, there are no "causal relations", only correlations. Whenever there are correlations between variables, their marginals can be written so that one variable "*looks caused*" by the other, but this statement does not have much value.

Indeed, we can always write
$p(a)=\sum_b p(a|b)p(b)$, which makes $A$ being "caused" by $B$, because $p(a|b)$ is *defined* as $p(a|b)\equiv p(a,b)/p(b)$, and the marginal $p(a)$ by $p(a)\equiv\sum_b p(a,b)$. While true, this is not a very useful observation.

It is meaningful to talk about causation in a context in which one can actually *exploit* such correlation. For example, if one can choose to have the variable $B$ assume the value $b$, then it is meaningful to talk about the conditional probabilities $p(a|b)$.
Notably, this is exactly the kind of thing that we cannot do in quantum mechanics: the measurement results are probabilistic, and therefore cannot be controlled.

Comment: probability is used to infer causation in various situations. so ("zen question") when is it valid reasoning?

Comment: @vzn I would say talking about cause/effect is more of a phenomenological/practical thing than anything else. It is meaningful to talk about causation *when you can exploit the correlation*. And this is strikingly relevant with the case at hand here: the correlations produced by QM *cannot be exploited*, basically by definition, and it therefore isn't meaningful/useful to talk about them being causally correlated

Comment: there is a widespread "assertion"/ _aka conventional wisdom_ the correlations "cant be exploited" but there seems to be no "proof"... anyway this is all an active area of research & there is copious writing on the subj...

Comment: @vzn [what do you mean "there is not proof"?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem) Also, theorem aside, it's quite easy to see that the marginal states obtained by partial trace are not affected by local operations on the other party

Comment: ok, good pt, but the (no communication thm) "proof" seems me to be very similar to the (not so well known) one by von Neumann against hidden variables eventually refuted by Bell. ie following from the premises, but based on a very subtle assumption, related to QM completeness.

Comment: @vzn I do not know what "proof" by von Neumann you are referring to

Comment: eg https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0408191 https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0499 invite further discussion here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9446/theory-salon

Comment: @user1892538 I'm not sure I follow. You say that it is irrelevant to discuss whether two events are the cause of one another, but isn't that exactly the point of my answer?

Comment: @user1892538 what I tried to express with this answer was indeed that the question of causation is not the interesting one. I did not appreciate this point when I originally asked the question. You say "correlations imply a common cause", but isn't that essentially the position that Bell's inequalities rule out? They show that a common cause is not enough to explain the statistics predicted by QM (when ruling out nonlocal interactions etc.).

Comment: @user1892538 sure, go ahead! The whole point of asking here is to gather other peoples' opinions. I don't see how that expression is not accurate though, as it is simply stating that we are using the causal structure of the picture

Comment: Quantum cryptography (a trace can be detected by doing a Bell’s inequalities test) and more generally Quantum Computing are ways to exploit the fact that the entanglement is a global property: the non local causality of QM can be leveraged (also Feynman realized that entanglement could be used for a new way to process information).

Comment: @Giulio indeed it can, but not by exploiting any sort of "causal connection" between measurement outcomes. Rather, one exploits the quantum correlations and the way they can be manipulated.

Comment: You have written: "*It is meaningful to talk about causation in a context in which one can actually exploit such correlation.*", that appears to be exactly the case, as you have confirmed also above: "*one exploits the quantum correlations and the way they can be manipulated*". So it contradicts your idea that "*the question of causality is ill-posed in this context*".

Comment: @Giulio eh, not really. To "exploit such correlation" here means to be able to control one of the variables to achieve something with the other. This is the context in which, I find, it is meaningful to talk about causation. This is quite different than what is done in q. communication and q. computation. In q. comm. one mostly exploit the correlations to build shared "secure" information (with the help of a classical channel). In QC one manipulates the enlarged Hilbert space to achieve speed-ups. You never "manipulate" one outcome result to change another, but work directly on the amplitudes

Comment: It is quite controversial. As counterexample, the seasons are caused by the orientation of the Earth's tilt with respect to the sun: whether one can control the cause or not doesn't make the causation less meaningful.

Comment: @Giulio well, maybe you can't in practice, but you model the system in such a way that it is at least in principle possible to do it. On the other hand, QM *by definition* tells you that, given fixed experimental circumstances, there is no way to "control" which outcome you are going to get. In other words, in QM the measurement outcomes cannot be controlled *even in principle*. More generally though, I think the main problem here is that in lack of a precise, mathematical, definition of what "causation" means, the whole discussion is not tremendously meaningful

Comment: I think the main problem here is what changes for you - as the OP of this question - if you call it "*causation*" or "*correlation*".  Bell said:”The correlations cry for explanation” and he was right. I think that your answer doesn't change this fundamental point.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Does Bell's theorem imply a causal connection between the measurement outcomes?

Bells Theorem is essentially about measuring outcomes on an experiment on the EPR paradox. This is the paradox where Einstein argued that QM was not complete because entangled systems showed that superluminal signalling was possible - contra special relativity. Bell himself wrote:

> If [a hidden variable theory] is local it will not agree with [[standard]] quantum mechanics, and if it agrees with [[standard]] quantum mechanics it will not be local. This is what the theorem says. *Speakable and Unspeakable in Quantum Mechanics*, John Bell

and he concluded:

> In a theory in which parameters are added to quantum mechanics to determine the results of individual measurements, without changing the statistical predictions, there must be a mechanism whereby the setting of one measuring device can influence the reading of another instrument, however remote. Moreover, the signal involved must propagate instantaneously, so that such a theory could not be Lorentz invariant.

A hidden variable theory means simply a deterministic theory. What this means that given a deterministic theory of QM where cause propagates locally, and this means physically and hence at or less than the speed of light, then it won't match all the predictions of standard QM. Alternatively, if it turns out this deterministic theory does match the predictions, then cause will propagate faster than light speed.

Now since the predictions of standard QM have been verified to a high degree of accuracy then Bells theorem shows that QM is

- not deterministic, or
- deterministic with cause propagating at faster than light speeds

Generally the second option is ruled out on the basis of relativity and this leaves the first option - that QM is *not* deterministic. What this means about entangled systems being non-local is left open. However, its shown through the [no communication theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem) of QI that no actual effective information can be signalled at faster than light speeds. So QM remains local in this second, weaker sense of locality.

**note**: [[my insertions]]

Comment: I don't really see how this relates to the question. Sure, QM does not allow for superluminal communication, but that is literally my opening sentence. Also, saying "*QM is not deterministic*" is debatable: it is entirely deterministic up to the moment a measurement is performed. What is *not* debatable is that measurement outcomes are (described by QM as) nondeterministic. My question is precisely about what this fact tells us about the causal connection between measurement outcomes (and the answer I personally found satisfying is that the question of causality is ill-posed in this context).

Comment: The fact that the hidden variables are deterministic seems irrelevant to the logical conclusion of the theorem in terms of non-locality (with the first meaning) or otherwise can you explain what you exactly mean by non-deterministic and how can this property (of being non-deterministic) satisfy both Bell's inequality and the causal locality as well (if A and B are spacelike separated)?

Comment: @gls: The evolution of the wavefunction is standardly said to evolve deterministically. This is a strange understanding of deterministic.

Comment: @giulio: In what way is it 'irrelevant'? Bells theorem is essentially about the kinds of predictions that a deterministic theory of QM can make. As for your second question not deterministic means not a hidden variable theory. I explained that in my answer.  As for your third question - I don't understand it. QM is non-deterministic and *violates* Bells inequalities.

Comment: @glS: Its actually a standard result that SR doesn't allow for for superluminal communication - not QM. QM is like Newtons theory in that it's not a relativistic theory - so just taking that theory by itself we can theoretically posit faster than light speeds without it being formally wrong.

Comment: Bell's theorem also excludes probabilistic theories. The causal structure described by the picture I included is also satisfied by probabilistic theories. There is no need to assume determinism at any point in the derivation. What you *are* assuming is that measurement outcomes are conditionally (on the hidden variable) uncorrelated.

Comment: @glS: What about the Born rule in QM - thats a probabilistic theory? Are you using probabilistic is a very specific technical way? I'm using determinism - in my answer - as a synonym for hidden variables theory. Thats strange because Bell specifically says in the quote above 'In a theory in which parameters are added to quantum mechanics to *determine* the results of individual measurements, without changing the statistical predictions, there must be a *mechanism* whereby the setting of one measuring device can influence the reading of another instrument, however remote'.

Comment: @gls: I just did a quick search for 'probabilistic theories and bells inequalities' I didn't see anything significant on the first couple of pages. Is there a sensible exposition somewhere of what you mean by this?

Comment: @MoziburUllah Born's rule is about the probabilities induced by measurements. QM is totally deterministic in the sense that the evolution of the wavefunction is deterministic up until the point one is measuring the system (that is, is coupling the system with a larger environment). Regarding Bell's theorem, it might be that in the original derivation one has to assume deterministic outcomes, but from CHSH onwards this is not the case. The standard reference here is https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2849.

Comment: @gls: Yeah, I know that - but I'm pointing out that this is a very different sense of what classical determinism means - particularly in Newtons theory. Generally, people will say that a throw of a dice is random. But if you look at its probaibility distribution, then that is fixed. That does not mean that throwing the dice has suddenly become deterministic. Using language this way in QM is conceptually confusing.

Comment: @gls: Interesting paper - particularly the synopsis. Thanks for digging it up.

Answer (score 1):

What is really important to understand before formulating any answers is the exact meaning of the words that enters into the context of Bell's theorem and in particular locality, realism and causality.

Locality and causality are linked together in what is defined as "*relativistic local
causality*".

Then it is unfortunate that realism - please let me quote wikipedia here - "is now somewhat different from what it was in discussions in the 1930s. It is more precisely called counterfactual definiteness".

I'm adding the previous sentence about the meaning of realism because the final answer to the OP question - which I want to rephrase as: does causality hold or not? - depends on which of the two - realism or locality - one chooses to abandon after Bell's theorem.

For example R. D. Gill [suggests](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.5103) that we should "relinquish not locality, but realism": in that case we would somehow arrive to the conclusion of the OP's answer, i.e. that "*the question of causality is ill-posed in this context*".

On the other hand, I would prefer the opposite choice, arriving to the opposite conclusion, that causality is meaningful and QM (or De Broglie–Bohm or any other theory which satisfies Bell's inequality) has to be non-local theory (important note, non-local in the sense of Bell's theorem, but of course we all agree about the signal locality or no-signaling principle or no-communication theorem).

Finally, a minor note should be added about the fact that the experimental verification of the inequality is subject to the closure of all the possible loopholes (free will, fair sampling and so on).

Comment: just one note: I am here totally assuming the assumptions of Bell's theorem to hold, and not in any way trying to go around them. The question is rather, *given the assumptions* ***and*** *conclusions of Bell's theorem*, is it correct to say that measurement outcomes are causally connected? The question arises from the fact that they are correlated, but this correlation cannot be explained by a common cause, which classically would lead to conclude that there must a causal link between them

Answer (score 0):

> does the fact that $p(a,b,x)$ cannot be factorized as $p(a,x)p(b)$ imply that there is a causal relation between the two measurement outcomes?

From a mathematical point of view that means that QM violates "*outcome independence*" . Together with the fact that $a$ and $b$ can be spacelike separated, this implies that QM violates local causality. This is not to be confused neither with the non-deterministic character of the theory nor with the possibility to exploit this feature to send FTL signals. Signal locality is indeed expressed by a different mathematical constraint: $p(a|x, y) = p(a|x)$ or equivalently $p(b|x, y) = p(b|y)$.

Nonetheless - whatever interpretation one chooses to explain the so-called collapse of the wave function - this kind of non-locality remains. For example Bohmian mechanics satisfies outcome Independence and fails to satisfy setting Independence. Back to QM, Bell's inequalities follow from the algebra of Hamilton's quaternions (more technically Bell quantum bound  is obeyed for the case when four commutators vanish and Bell's inequality can be given meaning in the formalism of C*-algebras ). Interestingly there is also a geometric interpretation of the hidden variables as the global phase curled up under the Hopf-fibration between the unit spinor and the Bloch vector - which is again (without dwelling into the proof check of any alternative theory) a non-local topological mapping.

Answer (score -2):

> My question is then precisely about these last statements: does the fact that p(a,b,x) cannot be factorized as p(a,x)p(b) imply that there is a causal relation between the two measurement outcomes?

No it doesn't imply any causal relation between the measurement outcomes. Bell's theorem sez that any hidden variable theory must be non-local to match the predictions of quantum mechanics. Those hidden variables are descriptors of a system that have a single measurable value. Quantum mechanics is not a hidden variable theory, so the Bell inequalities don't imply that quantum mechanics is non-local.

Rather, each system exists in multiple versions and those versions are matched up in the appropriate way when the measurement results from the entangled systems interact. For example, if particle 1 is entangled with particle 2, and particle 1 is measured at a point p1 spacelike separated from the measurement of particle 2 at point p2, then all of the possible outcomes happen for each measurement happen. When these outcomes are compared at some third point p3 after being coveyed there by local means, the matching takes place, but before that comparison they are not matched. This matching is done using quantum information that each system holds that can't be extracted by measurements on that system alone and so doesn't suffer decoherence.

For a detailed quantum mechanical account of how the Bell correlations happen see David Deutsch, Patrick Hayden, 'Information Flow in Entangled Quantum Systems', Proc. R. Soc. Lond. A 456(1999):1759-1774. available at http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007. And also David Deutsch, 'Vindication of quantum locality', Proc. R. Soc. A 468(2012), 531-544. available at http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223.

This account is given using what is commonly called the "many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics", which is just quantum mechanics taken literally as a description of how the world works. For reasons that are not well explained, this is controversial. There other "interpretations", some of which are alternative physical theories like the spontaneous collapse theory or the pilot wave theory. These are alternatives to quantum mechanics, not interpretations and they are in general non-local because they say that EPR type experiments have single outcomes. Other "interpretations" such as the Copenhagen or statistical interpretations don't make clear statements about what exists in reality and so no account can be given of what is happening in reality under those theories.

Comment: "*Rather, each system exists in multiple versions and those versions are matched up in the appropriate way when the measurement results from the entangled systems interact.*" => This is a very **non local** behavior.

Comment: @Giulio No. This is not non-local behaviour. The results from the measurements are copied from one system to another by virtue of systems interacting according to local equations of motion. When a system containing one result interacts locally with a system containing the other result, then those results become correlated. The information about that correlation then spreads out locally from the systems containing information about that interaction.

Comment: What you mean exactly? I have written the result of my experiment in the stone at point p1 and you at point p2 and they are spacelike separated. Then we meet locally in point p3 and we tell each other our results (I remember mine and you yours). How can you spread the information locally?

Comment: At point p1 you measure a system that exists in two or more versions. After the measurement there are two or more versions of the measurement results. Likewise at point p2. When the measurement results are compared they are matched in the right way when they are compared and not before.

Comment: There must be also two or more versions of me remembering different results... anyway, I think I have understood your point about the locality of the multiverse...

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer with a simple and clear example to show how information about correlation can spread out locally as per your comments above?

Comment: @Giulio I added an example.

Comment: ok, but *many-worlds* is only an interpretation of QM (and not mainstream). Thank you for including the above example, but your answer is not yet complete without at least an other standard QM interpretation, with an equivalent discussion of the locality and causality in that case.

Comment: The standard interpretation doesn't clearly what is and what is not real, so neither I nor anyone else can give such an account.

Comment: What I am asking to do - in order to have a fair answer - is to consider that the mainstream interpretation is that there is a *collapse* of the wave function (instead of the many world interpretation) and in that case it's evident that there is a non local causal link between the two entangled event (given by the collapse itself of the wave function). I'm not saying you should change your mind/position, just making the answer objective and palatable by all accounts (since there is a bounty ... and many people viewing this post).

Comment: @giulio I have modified the post to describe the account given by other "interpretations".