# Confusion around Bell's Theorem and Locality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality, locality, foundations, quantum-foundations

I recently got interested in foundational aspects of quantum mechanics and I have some questions:

[Bell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem) proves that any local, deterministic theory with statistical independence can't account for certain observed correlations. The standard QM formulation is usually considered local, with no determinism, but I just don't see how determinism can be false without locality also being false?

If an entangled particle pair has no pre-determined relative position, in which sense is the theory  local? Furthemore, if both particle states are undetermined before the measurement, why would the local act of measuring the first one give any certain information about the second one, which is completely undisturbed by our local operation? I don't see any reasonable notion of locality that can accomplish this.

I also don't see how the notion of determinism can be rigorously defined, while locality can easily be defined in a relativistic space-time.

EDIT:
I reviewed some of the discussion here, the issue i wanted to address can be stated more easily by “can a non-deterministic, relativistically local QM exist”? By deterministic, I mean a theory in which systems have defined properties before measurements.

My confusion is from the fact that these theories are not ruled out by Bell’s theorem, yet I can’t understand how they can exist at all. If a notion of locality is not even definable in non-deterministic models, then how come that QM is developed this way?

Comment: Locality is a very overloaded word in this context. Stick to equations and definitions in terms of equations to be on the safe side. Same applies to terms like "determinism".

Comment: "Determinism" is, as Tobias says, has different meanings in different contexts. Many (I do) equate "determinism" and "hidden variables" - which is fine in the general EPR-Bell line of thinking. But some object, and ultimately you're stuck in a battle of semantics. I don't know of any 2 folks who use these words (or "locality" for that matter) quite the same. OTOH the math is only explicit in the limited sense that the predictions of QM are well tested - so mostly everyone agrees on that. QM math doesn't have a true definition of locality, and all entangled systems have spatio-temporal extent.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRT5zXAwvBs&t=52m) is a podcast video discussing this where it mentions your exact conundrum at 52:00 (and it ends up agreeing with your conclusion). People are often concerned more with "realism" rather than "determinism" but unfortunately again you have as many proposed definitions for realism as there are people talking about it. Apparently John Bell's paper dealt with locality only and it was only later did people talk about local realism. See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.05452) for the history.

Comment: In fact a system of 2 entangled photons is also sometimes called a biphoton to indicate that it cannot be considered as 2 independent systems/particles. Biphotons have been created that span over 2 kilometers apart in distance, and pass Bell tests to show their entangled nature.  The previously unentangled component photons were generated from independent sources and never interacted. https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0409093.pdf

Comment: @MaximalIdeal I agree with what you say about definitions of "Realism".  But Realism was an explicit assumption in Bell 1964. See immediately after Bell's (14) "It follows that c is another unit vector..." which exactly follows from an assumption in EPR 1935. EPR assumed that every "element of reality" should be simultaneously real, even if only one at a time could be observed. Bell introduced the a/b/c nomenclature to show that assumption was not compatible with the predictions of QM.

Comment: "By deterministic, I mean a theory in which systems have defined properties before measurements." - that isn't compatible with standard notions of determinism. Well-defined classical properties may change over time in a random way. Conversely, measurements may "create" the measured property even in a deterministic theory (such as many-worlds with the wave function taken as the reality).

Comment: @benrg Not really disagreeing with your definition itself. Certainly it is possible quantum properties could change in an "apparently random" manner as they evolve, up to and including the act of measurement. But perfect correlations in entangled systems tends to rule that out (EPR 1935). I realize that MWI advocates label it "deterministic" anyway, but their definition won't satisfy everyone either. (I flatly reject that label for MWI, regardless of my opinion of MWI.) I would call Davyz2's definition reasonable (and certainly common enough), even though it may not satisfy everyone either.

Comment: Replying to "If a notion of locality is not even definable in non-deterministic models, then how come that QM is developed this way?"

Comment: Locality and determinism are completely different concepts. In QM, We always talk about probabilities before an act of a measurement, that means QM is Non-deterministic. A local theory is in which information can't travel faster than speed of light, in QM of entangled particles, there is no transfer of information by a carrier particle, the entangled pairs are having states which affects one another when a measurement is taken on one of the particle because these states were formed together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The standard QM formulation is usually considered local, with no
> determinism, but I just don't see how determinism can be false without
> locality also being false?

There are several ways to answer your questions, so I may as well start here. With the advent of Bell's Theorem, as well as the many experimental variations which support the predictions of QM, I would not say QM is generally considered "local". A term has arisen, "quantum nonlocality" (sometimes just "nonlocality"), to describe the kind of nonlocal effects associated with quantum mechanics. *Please note that signals cannot be transmitted nonlocally in any variation or interpretation of QM. The only effect that can be transmitted non-locally are ones that yield random outcomes.  Also note that there is no particular mechanism for nonlocality embedded in mainstream QM.*

As to determinism: there is no known source or "cause" for the random outcomes of the probabilistic predictions of QM. It is possible that some underlying cause will be discovered in the future, but don't bet on it. No experiment has so much as pointed to the existence of such a cause (or set of hidden variables). Of course, there are interpretations of QM that posit determinism - there just isn't any hard evidence to support that hypothesis.

So there may be neither locality NOR determinism - that would also be consistent with what we know. But Bell's Theorem merely tells us that one or the other must be false.

Recent experiments have led us much further down the road. The so-called "loopholes" in Bell have been closed to the satisfaction of most scientists. For example:

1. https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9810080

Violation of Bell's inequality under strict Einstein locality conditions (1998)
Gregor Weihs, Thomas Jennewein, Christoph Simon, Harald Weinfurter, Anton Zeilinger

*"We for the first time fully enforce the condition of locality, a central assumption in the derivation of Bell's theorem. The necessary space-like separation of the observations is achieved by sufficient physical distance between the measurement stations, by ultra-fast and random setting of the analyzers, and by completely independent data registration."*

And there are the incredible experiments with entanglement swapping. In these, distant photons (from independent sources) are entangled without ever existing in a common light cone.  The variations on these experiments violate strict locality, and in fact don't follow the classical rules of cause and effect (where cause must precede effect).

2. https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0201134

Experimental Nonlocality Proof of Quantum Teleportation and Entanglement Swapping (2002-2008)
Thomas Jennewein, Gregor Weihs, Jian-Wei Pan, Anton Zeilinger

*"Quantum teleportation strikingly underlines the peculiar features of the quantum world. We present an experimental proof of its quantum nature, teleporting an entangled photon with such high quality that the nonlocal quantum correlations with its original partner photon are preserved. This procedure is also known as entanglement swapping. The nonlocality is confirmed by observing a violation of Bell's inequality by 4.5 standard deviations. Thus, by demonstrating quantum nonlocality for photons that never interacted our results directly confirm the quantum nature of teleportation."*

And in fact the work of Zeilinger and his co-workers was recognized in the Physics Award by the 2022 Nobel Committee:

*"One of the most remarkable traits of quantum mechanics is that it allows two or more particles to exist in what is called an entangled state. What happens to one of the particles in an entangled pair determines what happens to the other particle, even if they are far apart. In 1997–1998, Anton Zeilinger conducted groundbreaking experiments using entangled light particles, photons. These and other experiments confirm that quantum mechanics is correct and pave the way for quantum computers, quantum networks and quantum encrypted communication."*

*"Among other things, [Zeilinger's] research group has demonstrated a phenomenon called quantum teleportation, which makes it possible to move a quantum state from one particle to one at a distance [distance here meaning outside a common light cone]."*

And further, the study of 3 particle entangled GHZ States casts further doubt on both locality and determinism. Papers on this get very complex very quickly.  Here is one where Zeilinger is the co-author (and he is the Z in GHZ). I only provide these references to give you the idea that Bell's Theorem has led to a proliferation of ground-breaking work on entanglement and the foundations of Quantum Mechanics.

3. https://www.drchinese.com/David/Bell-MultiPhotonGHZ.pdf

Multi-Photon Entanglement and Quantum Non-Locality (2002)
Jian-Wei Pan and Anton Zeilinger

*"We review recent experiments concerning multi-photon Greenberger–Horne–
Zeilinger (GHZ) entanglement. We have experimentally demonstrated GHZ
entanglement of up to four photons by making use of pulsed parametric down conversion. On the basis of measurements on three-photon entanglement, we have realized the first experimental test of quantum non-locality following
from the GHZ argument. Not only does multi-particle entanglement enable
various fundamental tests of quantum mechanics versus local realism, but
it also plays a crucial role in many quantum-communication and quantum computation schemes."*

Answer (score 3):

The OP made some edits to the question, and I'd like to address those specifically.

> EDIT: I reviewed some of the discussion here, the issue i wanted to
> address can be stated more easily by “can a non-deterministic,
> relativistically local QM exist”? By deterministic, I mean a theory in
> which systems have defined properties before measurements.
>
> My confusion is from the fact that these theories are not ruled out by
> Bell’s theorem, yet I can’t understand how they can exist at all. If a
> notion of locality is not even definable in non-deterministic models,
> then how come that QM is developed this way?

QM is mostly silent as to whether it is a) local non-realistic(or local non-deterministic or local but no hidden variables); b) nonlocal realistic; or c) nonlocal non-realistic. But you are asking specifically about a), so let's discuss that.  Note that some will argue that non-realistic, non-deterministic, and no hidden variables are different things.  But for this discussion, let's use your definition and refer to it as non-realistic (which is more often used).

The 1935 EPR paper (assuming you are familiar with it) defines "an element of reality" as being a probabilistic quantum outcome that can be predicted with certainty in advance. Realism is the assumption that if any quantum outcome can individually be predicted in advance, then all such must also be predictable in advance - even if such outcomes can be predicted simultaneously.  So spin (on any basis), momentum, etc. of entangled pairs would fall into this category. If all these outcomes could be predicted in advance, then they must be *predetermined*. The key point here: "pre" implying before.  The reality of a quantum property therefore should not depend on how the observer might choose to measure a system.

So what is an indeterministic/non-realistic interpretation?  It is any that does not have all of its properties predetermined.  The implication is: a) something far away affects the outcome (but you want to exclude this); or b) something in the future contributes to the outcome in some manner. It could also be something that is part of the measurement process itself.  In terms of the EPR paper, we might also say that indeterministic QM is observer dependent, i.e. subjective.  (You can see how quickly and easily we get lost in words...)  In fact, simply accepting the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle as complete/true/factual could be seen as accepting indeterminism.

@KenWharton, a respected contributor here, has studied and written on this subject extensively.  I would call attention to a series of his papers on Bell's Theorem and retrocausal class interpretations.  These have the features you are asking about.

1. https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04313

*"Bell's Theorem rules out many potential reformulations of quantum mechanics, but within a generalized framework, it does not exclude all "locally-mediated" models. Such models describe the correlations between entangled particles as mediated by intermediate parameters which track the particle world-lines and respect Lorentz covariance. These locally-mediated models require the relaxation of an arrow-of-time assumption which is typically taken for granted. Specifically, some of the mediating parameters in these models must functionally depend on measurement settings in their future, i.e., on input parameters associated with later times. This option (often called "retrocausal") has been repeatedly pointed out in the literature, but the exploration of explicit locally-mediated toy-models capable of describing specific entanglement phenomena has begun only in the past decade. A brief survey of such models is included here. These models provide a continuous and consistent description of events associated with spacetime locations, with aspects that are solved "all-at-once" rather than unfolding from the past to the future. The tension between quantum mechanics and relativity which is usually associated with Bell's Theorem does not occur here."*

2. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.05370.pdf

This addresses issues around entanglement swapping (which can occur without any specific speed restraint) while attempting to maintain locality (which you want).

In addition, there are other interpretations that are "local non-realistic" or perhaps better termed "local acausal".  The best known of these (but not all that well known) is Relational Blockworld.  Unfortunately, none of my references on it were in a format to really address the question at hand without excessive study.  Instead:

3. https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/retrocausality/

This touches on Relational Blockworld and its relationship to some of the ideas of Wharton et all in references 1. and 2.

So to answer your question: there are interpretations of QM that are explicitly local and non-realistic.  I would personally call MWI non-realistic as well, but its proponents would scream and shout that it is the most realistic.  At any rate, the interpretations debate rages.  My friends that are ardent professionals in the area of Quantum Field Theory point out that QFT is completely relativistic, and features local causality.  On the other hand, they acknowledge the obvious issues with FTL quantum teleportation and limits due to the uncertainty principle.

Comment: -- "The implication is: a) something far away affects the outcome (but you want to exclude this); or b) something in the future contributes to the outcome in some manner. It could also be something that is part of the measurement process itself." --

I don't see how option b) is any better than option a) with respect to locality, in a relativistically local space-time, you cannot have retro-causation. I don't see how giving up on determinism allows you to retain locality in any way. The "subjective" measurement also sounds quite dubious and non-rigorous.

Comment: @Davyz2 Part I: I am not pushing any interpretation, more describing how different ones address the Bell result (either locality and/or realism/determinism must be jettisoned), But novel experiments in the past 30 years have failed to favor any interpretation over another. The Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle (HUP) tells us that quantum systems - including entangled ones - do *not* have well-defined property values until an experimenter chooses a measurement basis in the future. That alone makes outcomes *subjective*, which you don't like. Neither did Einstein! But that result is rigorous.

Comment: @Davyz2 Part II: You deny there can be retrocausation in a local space time, yet there is every reason to consider the laws of physics (and certainly relativity) as time symmetric. As mentioned in reference 1: *"These locally-mediated models require the relaxation of an arrow-of-time assumption which is typically taken for granted. ... parameters in these models must functionally depend on measurement settings in their future."* Crazy? Maybe, but this nicely accounts for "troubling" results in rigorous delayed choice experiments. See figures 17b and 22c in https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.2930

Comment: @Davyz2: See also the [Kochen–Specker theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kochen%E2%80%93Specker_theorem), which is a companion to Bell's theorem. It shows that at least some of the underlying indeterminism is fundamentally tied to linear algebra, analogous to how the uncertainty principle is fundamentally tied to Fourier analysis.

Comment: Adding to @Corbin 's relevant comment: The Kochen-Specker (also called Bell-Kochen-Specker) theorem demonstrates that no non-contextual version of QM is viable. This goes somewhat farther than Bell's Theorem alone. Keep in mind that non-contextuality is generally the same as "objective realism", or "pre-determinism", or "observer independent reality". *"...we perform an all-or-nothing-type Kochen-Specker experiment to verify whether noncontextual hidden variables or quantum mechanics is right. The results strongly agree with quantum mechanics."* https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0209038

Comment: Another interpretation of indeterminism/nonrealism: events are not being influenced nonlocally or from the future, nor by the measurements process nor by the human mind. They simply produce a random outcome by themselves- the new information is created spontaneously. I'd say this is the simplest interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

> If an entangled particle pair has no pre-determined relative position, in which sense is the theory local? Furthemore, if both particle states are undetermined before the measurement, why would the local act of measuring the first one give any certain information about the second one, which is completely undisturbed by our local operation? I don't see any reasonable notion of locality that can accomplish this

I think there's some confusion in this sentence.

You can think of entangled particles as sharing a stronger form of correlation. Classically you can imagine them as being correlated in the sense that, for example, if one is black then the other is white, and *vice versa*. In the quantum case, the correlations are stronger than that, and whether you observe such correlations depends on the way you measure each one.

So the "local act of measuring the first one" can give "certain information about the second one" — provided we're talking about a maximally entangled pair and suitable choices of measurements — because they were correlated to begin with. Nothing particularly weird about this. It only gets weird when you realise that such correlations remain for (infinitely) many choices of measurement bases, in a way that can't be replicated classically.

This is also why the act of measuring gives information about the second particle even though the second particle is not disturbed by the act of measurement. You get information because there was a prior correlation (and you assume you know the structure of this correlation beforehand in this context). At the same time, even though after the measurement your description of the state of the second particle is changed (think of it as you updating your description of the second particle), the second particle is unperturbed in the sense that its reduced state is unaffected by the measurement outcome.

Nevertheless, you cannot explain the observation as simply due to shared correlations in the classical sense, hence why it's tempting to say that measuring one "actually affects" the other one, whatever that is taken to mean. See also *[Does Bell's theorem imply a causal connection between the measurement outcomes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/418413/58382)* for more info on this.

In conclusion, the theory remains local because the local state of the other particle is not affected by whatever you are doing to yours. At the same time, the correlations are (can be) "quantum", meaning that they cannot be simply explained by our lack of knowledge of some hidden variable, and therefore we might conclude that the link between the particles is "stronger than just correlations". But they still are "just correlations" because you cannot exploit them for superluminal information transfer in any way (which is just another way to phrase the fact that the local states are not affected by the measurements on the other side). So at the end of the day, they are both "just correlations" and "not just correlations", depending on how you choose to understand those words.

Comment: *"... because they were correlated to begin with.  ... In conclusion, the theory remains local because the local state of the other particle is not affected by whatever you are doing to yours..."* There is no requirement that entangled particles start off entangled. To entangle them, they don't even need to interact or ever exist in a common light cone (i.e. too far apart for any effect limited to c to traverse). That's nonlocality, the thing that Zeilinger demonstrated & received a Nobel for in 2022. And since QM is contextual, it's the remote measurement settings that dictate the statistics.

Comment: @DrChinese I mean... sure? I'm not sure whether you meant the comment in opposition to something I wrote or not. I don't think I said anything about the particles needing to "start off entangled". It doesn't really make any difference how the degrees of freedom at hand ended up entangled

Comment: You said: *"You get information because there was a prior correlation (and you assume you know the structure of this correlation beforehand in this context)."* There need be no prior connection or correlation. In fact, distant particles can be entangled after detection. And... entangled photons don't even need to ever exist at the same time to become entangled. Further, Bell teaches us that it is quite possible a measurement on one entangled particles imparts a change of some type on the other - we don't know for sure. My point is that the science on this has come a long way in recent years.

Comment: I don't really see the contradiction. Yes, they need to be correlated, as if the particles aren't correlated, they can't be entangled (of course, correlation isn't enough: it's a necessary but not sufficient condition). Yes, they don't need to be entangled before being separated. It doesn't really make much of a difference the temporal moment they get entangled. The only thing that matters is that the bipartite state that is being measured must be entangled (or more precisely, it needs to be nonlocal, which is not exactly the same thing: Wiseman 2006 and so on).

Comment: regarding "*Further, Bell teaches us that it is quite possible a measurement on one entangled particles imparts a change of some type on the other - we don't know for sure.*", this is just the usual objection. See all the related discussions about the topic. The solution just boils down to how exactly you define "imparts a change" etc.

Comment: You said: “ In conclusion, the theory remains local because the local state of the other particle is not affected by whatever you are doing to yours.” I can choose to remotely entangle distant photons. That is nonlocal action, plainly. See for example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.3991.pdf or https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4191 each of which discuss entanglement outside of the usual space time limitations. So I would not agree with your conclusion because it is experimentally falsified. And the experiments in fact follow standard QM theory.

Comment: @DrChinese yes, again, both things are true. The theory is local (in the sense of lack of superluminal information transfer, ie the no-communication theorem; obviously it's also nonlocal in the sense of Bell nonlocality; both things are true at the same time, albeit the terminology can be somewhat confusing if you're not used to it), and also you can remotely entangle photons (or more generally, you can remotely entangle degrees of freedom). There is no contradiction. There's nothing weird about this, these are all completely standard statements.

Answer (score -1):

> Bell's theorem proves that any local, deterministic theory with statistical independence can't account for certain observed correlations. The standard QM formulation is usually considered local, with no determinism, but I just don't see how determinism can be false without locality also being false?

The account of QM given by many sources is a kludge. It takes quantum mechanical equations of motion such as the Schrodinger equation and then adds an idea called collapse on top. Collapse is a process that supposedly picks one of the possible values of an observable and sez that is the value. In most accounts no explanation of collapse is given so we can't say much about such theories and don't need to discuss them further.

Some physicists try to come up with a variant of quantum theory that explains how collapse takes place. Such theories make predictions that differ from those of quantum theory

https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969

They are also non-local since Bell's theorem only actually relies on describing measurement outcomes in terms of stochastic variables. A stochastic variable is a physical quantity that has values that are picked with some probability out of a set of possible values. Such a variable could be local if the probability of measurement outcomes depended locally on the values of other physical quantities. Collapse theories effectively change quantum observables into stochastic variables so they are non-local.

> If an entangled particle pair has no pre-determined relative position, in which sense is the theory local? Furthemore, if both particle states are undetermined before the measurement, why would the local act of measuring the first one give any certain information about the second one, which is completely undisturbed by our local operation? I don't see any reasonable notion of locality that can accomplish this.

The answer to this question is a matter of controversy because the standard way of discussing quantum theory is a kludge that can be used to discuss predictions but not to give any account of what is happening in reality to produce those predictions.

There is a version of quantum theory that isn't a kludge. It involves taking the equations of quantum theory and trying to work out their implications without collapse. (What follows is a significant simplification for brevity.) What happens in this version of quantum theory is that measurable physical quantities are described by quantum observables represented by Hermitian operators. The possible results of measurements of these observables are the eigenvalues of those operators. These different possible values can interfere with one another under some circumstances such as single particle interference experiments. There is no collapse but when information about a measurement result is copied that prevents interference between the different values of an observable:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189

https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2832

As a result this theory predicts the existence of many variants of the world we see around us and is commonly called the many worlds interpretation. This is a somewhat sensational term for just taking QM equations of motion seriously as a description of how the world works.

If the observables of a system depend only on the observables of systems with which it has interacted the the relevant quantum mechanical theory is local. There is an explanation of how entanglement correlations arise from such a local theory as a result of quantum information being carried in decoherent quantum systems in a locally inaccessible form:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223

https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328

The correlations don't arise until information about the measurement results from each system are brought together, e.g. - by light from one side of the lab travelling to the other side of the lab.

There is a local theory about how entanglement works: quantum theory. I haven't found any other account of the mechanism by which entanglement correlations are created.

Comment: This is not mainstream physics. It is pushing a specific interpretation of QM called the Many Worlds (MWI). The pros and cons of QM interpretations belongs in their own Q&A. Importantly, it is not generally accepted that MWI is local (or deterministic for that matter) - that is a leftover idea from the early days of MWI. With the advent of hundreds of experiments demonstrating nonlocality, no one except hand-waving MWI proponents take that view seriously.

Comment: The results of entanglement experiments match the probabilities predicted by quantum theory, which are not compatible with local realistic (stochastic) theories. They are compatible with local quantum theory. The latest paper explaining the locality of quantum theory given above was written in 2020 and there have been other papers since then that continue to explain these issues, such as https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.14959.

Comment: The Nobel was awarded in 2022 to Zeilinger for experimentally demonstrating nonlocality, as correctly predicted by standard QM. Standard QM is generally accepted as being nonlocal, except by a shrinking group of  deniers at this point. It really makes more sense for MWI adherents to accept the obvious, and adjust their interpretation accordingly.

Comment: @DrChinese The fact that some physicists say that  Bell correlations show QM and reality are non-local is irrelevant since they have no explanation of what is happening in reality to produce those correlations. The only existing explanation is the one in my answer. Also scientific knowledge is created by pointing out problems with existing scientific ideas and coming up with new ideas to solve those problems as explained by Karl Popper, so following your prescription is anti-scientific.

Comment: You have Popper’s position wrong.He is well known for pushing for theories that can be tested and potentially be falsified. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Popper  MWI added absolutely nothing of any use to the working standard in its 65 year history. MWI proponents spend their time trying to keep up with advancements in orthodox QM. That’s their right of course, but don’t expect any points for accomplishing nothing except pure speculation. To date, MWI is as convincing as the idea that we live in a simulation.

Comment: @DrChinese You've got it the wrong way round. The MWI claims the equations of motion of QM are accurate as a description of reality so it makes specific predictions, which include decoherence, interference, entanglement and so on. The "standard" interpretation sez those equations are false under some unexplained circumstances, so it amounts to saying "QM is true, except when it's not", which is not testable.

Comment: You made my point. MWI adopted all QM theoretical predictions. And continues to as each new discovery is made. Quite contrary to your comment, there are no testable differences between orthodox QM and MWI, Bohmian Mechanics or any other interpretation. As is generally agreed, folks are free to select whatever interpretation helps your mental picture or overall understanding. I just don’t get why anyone would call MWI local, but hey, call it what makes you feel better. Please consider this my last comment in this thread, as we are way off track. You get the last words.

Comment: Your claim that interpretations of QM are untestable is mostly false and well known to be false in the literature https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/460549/28512